# role based creation of users in Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api

i have Three entities User, Institution and Role.
1)one to many between user and institution
2)and many to many between User and Role

-------user-------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"user"})
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"users"})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

-------institution-------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"institution" , "user"})
    private Set<User> user;
    }
```

-------role-------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"roles"})
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Those are my 3 entities and tables in MySql
i have 7 roles
•   Super-User
•   Bank-Admin
•   Bank-Support
•   Bank-Service
•   Merchant-Admin
•   Merchant-Support
•   Merchant-service

The super-User can create a user of any role

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        String rawpassword = user.getPassword();
        String encodedpasswrod = passwordencoder.encode(rawpassword);
        user.setPassword(encodedpasswrod);
        userrepository.save(user);
        return "user saved with name: " + user.getName();
    }
```

this api works and i can set the role to anything in my api json body

But  want that if the User is  Bank-Admin he can only create Bank-Support and Bank-Service
im trying to create a new API which can only create a user with those 2 specific roles.
and then restrict the bank admin to access the other API that can create users of any kind.

is there any other way to do it and if no how can i do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your custom implementation of User Entitlement.

Like according to login person, you will get that login person role, and according to your criteria just put validation like check that entity he is trying to add is he eligible to create it.

```
Map<String, List<String>> roleUserAccessMap = new HashMap<>();
roleUserAccessMap.put("Bank-Admin", Arrays.asList("Bank-Support", "Bank-Service"));
```

Just check like below

```
        String loginPersonRole="Bank-Admin"; //This value should get from logged-in person context
        if(roleUserAccessMap.containsKey(loginPersonRole) && roleUserAccessMap.get(loginPersonRole).contains(newuserrole) ){
            //proceed ahead with Add api
        }else{
            System.out.println("You do not have enough privileage to create Use");
        }
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much it! i will try it now 
but i did not understand one thing , how will i create the user with only these 2 specific role?
like the how can i implement it in a way that only those 2 roles can be added if the logged in user is a bank-admin
thank you so much for your help

Comment: User can be create with any role, you just need to verify before adding it into DB that global level map contains that role. If contains then only proceed ahead.

Comment: but how will that prevent a bank-admin from creating a Super-User?

Comment: i can download it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220221/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-jayzee).

Comment: hey Sorry but are u still in the chat?